# Como pasar a una funcion para mejor organizacion en Python

Tags: python, function

Buenas tengo varias partes de codigo que quiero pasar a funciones y necesito una breve explicacion con un ejemplo de una porcion de mi codigo:

```
from xlrd import open_workbook

book = open_workbook("archivo.xlsx")
for sheet in book.sheets():
    for rowidx in range(sheet.nrows):
        row = sheet.row(rowidx)
        for colidx, cell in enumerate(row):
            if cell.value == 4072:
                var = str(row[2])
                print(var)
```

como puedo pasar a una funcion eso? gracias

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Una función no es más que un bloque de código con un nombre, pero que tiene la particularidad de poder recibir parámetros y retornar resultados.

La forma general es (en este ejemplo recibe dos parámetros):

```
def nombre_funcion(par1, par2):
    bloque de código
    que puede acceder a las variables par1, par2
    que puede contener return expresion
```

Cuando invocas a la función así: `nombre_funcion(expr1, expr2)`, se ejecutará el bloque de código de la función y las variables `par1` `par2` dentro de la función tendrán los valores que hayas puesto en `expr1`, `expr2` al llamarla.

Si la función contiene `return expresion`, el resultado de evaluar esa expresión será el valor retornado. En el punto de la invocación puedes recibir ese resultado y asignarlo a una variable, por ejemplo así:

```
result = nombre_funcion(expr1, expr2)
```

En tu caso, convertir el código en función puede ser tan simple como esto (en este caso no recibe ningún parámetro ni retorna ningún resultado):

```
def obtener_valores():
    book = open_workbook("archivo.xlsx")
    for sheet in book.sheets():
        for rowidx in range(sheet.nrows):
            row = sheet.row(rowidx)
            for colidx, cell in enumerate(row):
                if cell.value == 4072:
                    var = str(row[2])
                    print(var)
```

Pero estaríamos infrautilizando el potencial de las funciones. Puede ser útil que el nombre del fichero sea un parámetro, y así la misma función serviría para procesar diferentes ficheros. También puede ser útil que el número especial `4072` sea otro parámetro y así la función serviría para encontrar otros números. Finalmente veo que imprimes algo que está en la columna 2 de la fila. Ese `2` podría ser otro parámetro para que así la función pudiera mostrar otra columna.

En general, donde veas "expresiones prefijadas" en tu código, puede ser útil cambiarlas por parámetros para que así la función sea usable en más escenarios.

Quedaría así:

```
def obtener_valores(excel, dato, col):
    book = open_workbook(excel)
    for sheet in book.sheets():
        for rowidx in range(sheet.nrows):
            row = sheet.row(rowidx)
            for colidx, cell in enumerate(row):
                if cell.value == dato:
                    var = str(row[col])
                    print(var)
```

Y la llamarías así:

```
obtener_valores("archivo.xlsx", 4072, 2)
```

Puedes también hacer uso de la posibilidad que python te ofrece de dar valores por defecto a los parámetros, para que no tengas que especificarlos en la llamada. Así:

```
def obtener_valores(excel, dato=4072, col=2):
    book = open_workbook(excel)
    for sheet in book.sheets():
        for rowidx in range(sheet.nrows):
            row = sheet.row(rowidx)
            for colidx, cell in enumerate(row):
                if cell.value == dato:
                    var = str(row[col])
                    print(var)
```

He dejado el primer parámetro como obligatorio, por lo que ese siempre hay que ponerlo al llamar a la función, pero los otros dos son opcionales y si no los pones tomarán el valor por defecto. Así, cualquiera de las siguientes sintaxis es posible a la hora de llamarla:

```
obtener_valores("archivo.xlsx")            # dato sería 4072 y col sería 2
obtener_valores("archivo.xlsx", 4000)      # dato sería 4000 y col sería 2
obtener_valores("archivo.xlsx", 4000, 3)   # dato sería 4000 y col sería 3
obtener_valores("archivo.xlsx", col=3)     # dato sería 4072 y col sería 3
obtener_valores("archivo.xlsx", dato=4010) # dato sería 4010 y col sería 2
```

Finalmente, esta función no retorna resultados sino que va imprimiendo los datos a medida que los encuentra. ¿Y si en lugar de imprimirlos quisiéramos sumarlos todos? ¿O contar cuántos son? ¿O ...? (ya me entiendes)

Sería mejor si la función en lugar de imprimir las cosas, simplemente lo retornara y que ya sea el programa principal quien decida qué hacer con esos datos.

Podemos por tanto cambiar la función para que cree una lista en la cual irá guardando los datos que encuentre, para finalmente retornar esa lista:

```
def obtener_valores(excel, dato=4072, col=2):
    book = open_workbook(excel)
    encontrados = []
    for sheet in book.sheets():
        for rowidx in range(sheet.nrows):
            row = sheet.row(rowidx)
            for colidx, cell in enumerate(row):
                if cell.value == dato:
                    var = str(row[col])
                    encontrados.append(var)
    return encontrados
```

Si ahora llamas a la función (con cualquiera de las sintaxis antes vistas), no saldrá nada por pantalla. Pero puedes guardar el resultado en una variable y usarla para lo que quieras. Por ejemplo, imprimirlo:

```
resultado = obtener_valores("archivo.xlsx")  # dato sería 4072 y col sería 2
print("Encontrados", len(resultado), "valores")
for dato in resultado:
    print(dato)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la bien explicada respuesta que me has dado, me pongo a practicar, saludos.